# Blocking in Dispose method

Tags: c#, .net, blocking, synchronous, idisposable

Can blocking in `Dispose()` method (synchronous variant) **anyhow** influence GC process?

Supposing:

- classes with no explicit finalizers,
- no real resource allocation/freeing within `Dispose`, just abusing the pattern to inject some code at the point of `Dispose` call

1. Up to now, I understood `Dispose` as a "normal" method, which also could "accidentally" be called by compiler generated code from some syntactic sugar constructs, like `using (var i = new Something(...)){}` or `using var i = new Something(...)` and if `using` is not suitable for us (from any reason), we just call it directly;
2. This implies, any blocking operation inside means only delay at the point of `Dispose` execution, right?
3. This implies, GC does not care about `Dispose` at all and just collects any instance, when there are no references to it, regardless of `Dispose` being called or not, right?
4. From above I imply that under mentioned conditions, there is no reason for any memory leak nor GC influence, when working with instances blocking in Dispose, right?

Example of such class:

```
class DisposeBlocker : IDisposable
{
    private Task localWork;
    private Task remoteWork;
    ...
    DisposeBlocker(Task work)
    {
        remoteWork = work;
    }

    void Dispose()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {} // CPU Bound
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Should be ok too, right?
        Task.Delay(1000).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // Is this still ok? Thread pools, contexts, similar stuff...
        Task.WhenAll(localWork, remoteWork).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // Same as the previous one, right?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct.

If it has no finalizer, GC will not care about the `Dispose` method.

This sounds like a big code smell, though: if `Dispose` is necessary, I would imagine it would be desirable to ensure it is called in most cicumstances, ergo you need a finalizer. And finalizers **MUST NOT BLOCK** or throw an exception under any circumstances.

It's also unexpected for `Dispose` to block either. So you really should avoid this kind of setup.

Comment: Very true. It's worth noting that C# 8.0 introduced an async disposal pattern which takes care of the example in the question